# Drupal HTML filter issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My requirement is very simple.

I want to add some html in a static page body.

I created a content type called Page.

I am adding HTML text into the body.

[image]

HTML is saved in database correctly.

But when I saw the same in front end it is showing HTML.
[image]

I am new to Drupal, But have 6 years of experience in php.
Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is problem with your text format settings. You can select different text format every time you make content and you can set up default one for every content type. Make sure you using text format which you set up for proper content display:
[image]

Assuming you are using "Full HTML" text format go on:

```
admin/config/content/formats
```

[image]

Click configure and make sure you turn off option display HTML as plain text:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, All the settings what you said is what I am using.

Comment: And? You still have problem with HTML output? What text editor you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify text format type.
Could you find text format area in content edit page?

If you want to display as html page, you need to specify "Full HTML" in text format area.

[image]

Comment: How to get that option?

Comment: You can get the option in content editing page. If you can't see this option, please check `Structure > Content types`.You can select **manage_display**, you can select default text format too.

Comment: Or you can select **manage_field** and select **edit**, if **Text processing** is  Plain text, you need to change to Filtered text (user selects text format).

Comment: Could you tell me your list and detail of **manage_fields** settings of content type? I want to see FIELD TYPE of LABEL=body.

Comment: could you please share your skype id. I will share the login credentials